# Filter Deletes during git svn clone?

Tags: git, git-svn

Problem: Legacy svn repo has a directory that is synced from user config on a prod server.

The sync effectively:

- deletes all files
- commits
- copies all files
- commits

Is it possible to filter out all of the file deletes during a git svn clone of this repo?

And subsequent git svn fetches as well?

I don't necessarily want to filter the entire commit just the parts that delete files.

This would mean changing the subsequent add files to become modify files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you want more control over your repo conversion, you may want to consider using [Reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon/) rather than git-svn

---

Owing to the way that Git works, the impact of these evil practices in SVN are less severe than you think though.

Firstly, Git itself has no notion of "file history". There is no such thing as a "file modify" like there is in SVN or other VCS systems. Git only remembers a tree of files. And then another tree of files. Etc.

If you compare HEAD to HEAD^^ (where HEAD^ is the intervening "deleted" commit), you will get results no different to those you'd get if you managed to leave the "deleted" revision out altogether.

In addition, the storage requirements will not be very much greater - Git stores whole objects and compares them for similarity when making packs, unlike SVN which uses delta compression (and thus depends on that file history). Tree A + empty tree + Tree B (composed of mostly the same files) will take a very tiny extra bit of space compared to missing out the empty tree revisions.

Comment: The concern here is having a useful history of the files.  This is not a repo conversion, but rather a repo mirror.  The svn repo is still actively receiving SVN commits.  I've brought the issue up with the maintainer but the resolution is scheduled as low priority.

Comment: The SVN commits from the three sources are effectively interleaved.  Is there a way I could deinterleave them.  Make three mirrors that each take every third commit with an offset?

Comment: Actually each source has a unique commit message that it uses everytime.  So maybe I just need to filter the commits on the commit message into three new repos?

Comment: I think `git read-tree` might be what you want - see my blog for inspiration http://strangeowl.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/grafting-history-with-git.html?m=1

Comment: Say I had a git repo that had three commit sources; Alpha, Beta, and Gamma.  They all use foo@bar as there name and email.  On a daily basis each source wipes the directory, copies in their unique files, and then commits.  Each commit source applies a message of their name respectively.  How would I break this into three new git repos that only contain the commits of one of the commit sources respectively.  eg a repo just for Alpha's commits, a repo just for Beta's commits, and a repo just for Gamma's commits.

Comment: @ÆtherSurfer If each committer is readily identifiable, you can adapt my method for merging branches linked to split them ; emit a log of commit / tree SHA1s, with additional fields that identifier the committers or otherwise allow you to filter them, then use grep to split the lines into their own files. Use each file to drive git read-tree / git commit pairs to form new branches with just the commits you want.